# Using AWK, print $1 (First column) if the string in the column starts with a specific string?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Firstly I would like to say that I am aware of the many questions here on StackOverflow regarding AWK and regular expressions. I already tried searching different questions and answer, tested multiple answers and none worked.

I have a list that is generated by the command:

```
iostat -dx | awk ' { print $1 }'
```

It outputs the following:

```
extended
device
ada0
ada1
ada2
pass0
pass1
pass2
```

I want to output only the lines starting with ada...
ada0, ada1, ada2.

Here are some commands I tried, and they all output nothing:

```
iostat -dx | awk '($1 == "^ada") { print $1 }'
iostat -dx | awk '($1 == "/^ada.*$/") { print $1 }'
```

This one outputs `device` (??):

```
iostat -dx | awk '($1 ~ /^d[ada]*/ ) { print $1 }'
```

**Important:** I can not use grep for this, since this is being runned on a Docker Image that DOES NOT have GREP, only AWK. I am very much aware of the command "iostat -x | grep "ada" | awk '{print $1}'", but unfortunatelly I can not use that.

Comment: `iostat -dx | awk '/^ada/ { print $1 }'` should work or `awk '$1 ~ /^ada/ { print $1 }'`

Comment: `^d[ada]*` means "d" followed by "a", "d", or "a" zero or more times.

Comment: You're mixing up regular expressions (delimited with `/.../` and compared with `~` or `!~`, and function-compared with `match()`) with strings (delimited with `"..."` and compared with `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, etc. and function-compared with `index()`). Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression should just be `^ada`, as in your first attempt. But the regexp should be inside `//`, not quotes, and you have to use `~` to compare it.

```
iostat -dx | awk '$1 ~ /^ada/ { print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am very much aware of the command "iostat -x | grep "ada" | awk
> '{print $1}'", but unfortunatelly I can not use that.

Just replacing `grep "ada"` using `awk` in above gives

```
iostat -x | awk '/ada/' | awk '{print $1}'
```

which might be written more concisely as

```
iostat -x | awk '/ada/{print $1}'
```

Note that this will print all lines containing `ada` anywhere, like that with grep you have shown.

As side note if `grep` is prohibited you might replace simple `grep` commands using `awk` as shown above or using `sed` as follows

```
iostat -x | sed -n '/ada/p' | awk '{print $1}'
```

`-n` does turn off default printing, `/ada/p` means if line contains `ada` do print it

Comment: Add the leading anchor `^` to show what the OP actually needs. Also, you never need sed when you're using awk so that final script isn't a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2 : testing through all awk variants I have to illustrate portability of solution :

```
% cat iostat.txt | gawk -te 'NF=/^ada/'
ada0
ada1
ada2
% cat iostat.txt | gawk -ce 'NF=/^ada/'
ada0
ada1
ada2
% cat iostat.txt | gawk -Sbe 'NF=/^ada/'
ada0
ada1
ada2
% cat iostat.txt | gawk -ne 'NF=/^ada/' 
ada0
ada1
ada2
ada2
% cat iostat.txt | gawk -Pe 'NF=/^ada/' 
ada0
ada1
ada2
% cat iostat.txt | gawk -e 'NF=/^ada/'
ada0
ada1
ada2
% cat iostat.txt | mawk  'NF=/^ada/'
ada0
ada1
ada2
% cat iostat.txt | mawk2  'NF=/^ada/'
ada0
ada1
ada2
% cat iostat.txt | nawk  'NF=/^ada/'
ada0
ada1
ada2
```

UPDATE : just realized one could make it **extremely** succinct :

```
iostat -x | mawk 'NF=/^ada/'

ada0
ada1
ada2
```

or make it even simpler :

```
iostat -x \
           \
           | mawk '!_<NF' FS='^ada'

ada0
ada1
ada2
```

And if you wanna even skip the shell quoting part :

```
mawk2 -F^ada NF==2 
mawk2        NF==2 FS=^ada
```

And even more exotic approaches :

```
mawk '$_!=$NF' FS='^ada[0-9]+'

ada0
ada1
ada2

mawk '_~$NF' FS='^ada[0-9]+'

ada0
ada1
ada2
```

And if you prefer gnu-gawk instead, then this is an excellent example of why RT exists :

```
gawk -e '$_=RT' RS='ada[0-9]+'

ada0
ada1
ada2
```

And if you REALLY like to use unconventional approaches that borderlines on being counter-intuitive and illogical :

```
mawk     '$NF<"<"'  FS='^ada[0-9]+'
mawk     '$NF<=">"' FS='^ada[0-9]+'
mawk  '!_!~NF'      FS='^ada[0-9]+'
mawk '_~_!~NF'      FS='^ada[0-9]+'

ada0
ada1
ada2
```

Comment: Even if this technique works, I wouldn't recommend it as a solution. This isn't Code Golf, there's no prize for using a shorter solution that's also more confusing. I'm an expert programmer and it took me a little extra thinking to understand why `NF=/regexp/` does what's desired. And it also doesn't generalize well to other columns.

Comment: @Bramar : if you think this is me doing code golfing, you haven't seen nothing yet =p